# How to append data in django import?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-import-export

I am uploading excel files through Django import. Whenever I import new files the existing rows are replaced with the new imported data. But I need the existing data as it is and the I want the new rows to be appended to the existing rows. How can we achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If there is 'id' attribute - or other primary key that you are using in your model - remove that from the data being imported.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `import_id_fields`

Example:

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        import_id_fields = ('isbn',)
```

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=import_id_fields